# R - f_num, but with comma

Tags: r

The `f_num` function from the `numform` package will remove leading zeros from a number:

```
f_num(0.1)
```

Output:

```
.1
```

I need this very same thing, but with a comma instad of the period. It would also be great if the functionality of the `f_num` function which allows you to round up the number of decimals would be kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a custom alternative(see note below):

```
detrail <- function(num,round_dec=NULL){

   if(!is.null(round_dec)){
    num<-round(num,round_dec)
   }
   gsub("^\\d\\.",",",num)

 }
 detrail(0.1)
[1] ",1"
 detrail(1.1)
[1] ",1"

detrail(0.276,2)
[1] ",28"
```

**NOTE**:

- To read this as numeric, you'll need to change options(OutDec) to `,` instead of `.` ie `options(OutDec= ",")`. I have not done this as I do not like changing global options.[See Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236440/as-numeric-with-comma-decimal-separators)
- This also removes any number that is not zero. Disable this by using `0` instead of `\\d`.